# Create Chained Seeds on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a issue here, i'm chaining  a Gender + Category + Subcategory seeds of products.

**Seeds**

```
g = Gender.create(:gender => 'Man')
g.categories.create(:name => "Clothes")


g = Gender.create(:gender => 'Woman')
g.categories.create(:name => "Accessories")


m = Category.find_by_name("Clothes")
m.subcategories.create(:name => "T-shirts" )


f = Category.find_by_name("Accessories")
f.subcategories.create(:name => "Rings" )
```

**Model Relation**

**Gender**

- has_many :categories   has_many :subcategories, through: :categories
- accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories,  :subcategories
- attr_accessible :gender, :categories_attributes,
  :subcategories_attributes

  **Category**
- belongs_to :gender
- has_many :subcategories
- accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories
- attr_accessible :name, :gender_id

**Subcategory**

- belongs_to :categories
- attr_accessible  :name,  :category_id

The issue is: Every time that i create the seeds the Woman subcategories is created on Man Subcategories Table. someone can helpme on this?

thank's

Comment: Are subcategories different tables? Can you post what your model relationships look like (eg has_many, belongs_to, etc.)

Comment: right, just a moment